# C++ set memory address to value

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I am currently making 2 programs. One of them will set a value, display the memory value and the value of the variable. Next it will wait for the user to press enter and it will show the value again. The next program will set the memory address directly, therefore modifying the value in the other code.

Here is my pointer1.cpp file:

```
  1 #include "iostream"
  2 using namespace std;
  3 
  4 
  5 
  6 int main()
  7 {
  8     int x = 100;
  9     cout << "The memory of \"x\" is " << &x << ". X = " << x << endl;
 10     cin.get();
 11     cout << x << endl;
 12 }
```

An example output is:

```
The memory of "x" is 0x7fff578589ac. X = 100

100
```

How would I then be able to make my second application to modify the memory address `0x7fff578589ac`?

Thanks.

Comment: This address is only valid inside your current applications context. Another program sees something totally different at this address. They are virtual addresses and it's totally OS dependent where they appear in your physical RAM. So you actually can't do that.

Comment: What is the practical use case of this? Is this for hacking/disturbing other programs?

Comment: Fortunately, operating systems don't work like that any more.

Comment: @WernerHenze I am not hacking apps, instead I want to learn how its done so I know how it works and how to check if my program is vulnerable.

Comment: A debugger is an example of a program that can do what you want with your "second program": it can attach to a process and modify some specific logical address in that process' memory space. This is highly system specific functionality, and not for beginners. If you just want to have two processes share memory, then look up the Boost library's support for memory mapped files.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with pure C++. You will have to turn to operating system methods.

On Windows for example you could use APIs such as `OpenProcess` and `WriteProcessMemory` to modify memory of another process.

Because this way is rather slow an often used alternative is to load your program into the address space of the target process you want to modify. On Windows this would be possible by making your program a DLL and getting it into the target (see "DLL Injection").

Because you commented about whether you program is vulnerable: If your attacker has access to your machine, yes. If your attacker has privileges to open your process with write access, yes.

Comment: So you mean that I cannot modify address values directly using C++ code? so I have to use things such as `OpenProcess` and `WriteProcessMemory` on Windows? If so, what would I do on OSX/Linux?

Comment: @iProgram The equivalent on Linux should be `ptrace`, but I think it requires a lot more privileges.

Comment: @iProgram No sorry, I meant you cannot do it with pure C++. The WinAPI is easily used in C++ code (and other OS APIs aswell for that matter).

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I don't mind using root privileges since I am the administer of the computer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Processes have their own set of memory in their address space. Also you are trying to modify value(or a variable) in a process which has terminated and the variables are garbage collected.

Comment: The app will be open. Hence the `cin.get()`. Also is this an answer or comment?

Answer (score 0):

In linux use `ptrace` system call. In win32, you can use `ReadProcessMemory`, `WriteProcessMemory`. But to use them you need to open the first process using `OpenProcess`